# time conversion from Unix Timestamp

Tags: java, date, datetime, xml-rpc

A server I am a member of has an xml-rpc API that I am connecting to. In it there is a function called "player.seen" that returns a Unix time stamp of when the "player" was last seen. I am trying to use this number to display how long it's been since the user has been seen. For some reason, it is not giving the proper values:

Old code: http://pastebin.com/tPe6mkyJ

I have tried re-writing the script in many different ways, but forgot to back them up. I am wondering if any of you know a better way to accomplish this conversion.

EDIT:
after editing my code to use joda-Time, I am still getting incorrect values. For example, player "pomi44" has not been seen in 15 days, 9 hours, 10 minute according to the in-game /seen command. My program outputs "1 days, 18 hours, 18 minutes, 10 seconds".

New code:

```
            Object[] params1 = new Object[]{API_KEY, playerName};
            String result = (String) client.execute("player.seen", params1);

            int timeStamp = Integer.parseInt(result);

            Date curDate = new Date();

            DateTime start = new DateTime(timeStamp * 1000L);
            DateTime end = new DateTime(curDate.getTime());
            Period period = new Period(start, end);

            int seconds = period.getSeconds();
            int minutes = period.getMinutes();
            int hours = period.getHours();
            int days = period.getDays();

            System.out.println(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, "  + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds.");
```

I have tried different numbers in place of "1000", but all give incorrect values. For example, player "pomi44" hasn't been seen for 15 days, 9 hours, and 10 minutes according to the in-game /seen command. My program outputs "1 days, 18 hours, 18 minutes, 10 seconds" for pomi44.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Joda-Time has a bunch of utilities for working with time... Offhand I think you'd want to construct two Instants, make an [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html) of them, then convert that to a Period to extract the different fields (days, hours, etc..). But I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Converting `long` to `int` isn't a good idea:

```
int TimeStamp_now = (int) curDate.getTime();
```

With the above statement you might be losing some information.

I suggest you to use [Joda Time Library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html). It has concept of [periods](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html).

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(timeStamp * 1000L);
DateTime end = new DateTime(curDate.getTime());
Period period = new Period(start, end);
```

`org.joda.time.Period` has methods `getDays`, `getHours`, `getMinutes` etc. to get those fields of the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using date not using Jodatime, i think joda time is the way to go(it's just all round nicer) however this should do it without needing jodatime

```
String result = (String) client.execute("player.seen", params1);
int timeStamp = Integer.parseInt(result);
Date then=new Date(timeStamp*1000L);
Date now = new Date();
long difference = now.getTime() - then.getTime();
```

Comment: it should be timestamp there, not result, im trying to help. also you are comparing integers in yours, this compares dates. I would aslo like to note "give incorrect values." in your question isn't very helpful. how wrong? what is wrong?

Comment: I've tried that in http://pastebin.com/tPe6mkyJ , getting the difference in Unix time-stamp is not the issue, converting from the time-stamp difference to a readable length of time in hours, minutes, etc is.